# I want to set a frequency on my time-series data (my data is in step of five minutes)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have data of electricity consumption of one month (each reading is taken in step of five minutes) and I want to set a frequency in this dataset. Please help me (If you want to see my data then I can provide please inform me)

In jupyter notebook I have tried codes like, (let, df = my_data)

```
df = pd.read_excel('practice.xlsx',index_col=0,parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])
df = df.asfreq(freq='5T')


my data (in which I want to set frequency)

    df.head()

    Date_Time              Actual Load
    2019-06-01 00:05:00     5414.0
    2019-06-01 00:10:00     5385.5
    2019-06-01 00:15:00     5330.8
    2019-06-01 00:20:00     5308.3
    2019-06-01 00:25:00     5278.6

    df.tail()

    Date_Time               Actual Load
    2019-06-30 23:35:00     6333.9
    2019-06-30 23:40:00     6291.7
    2019-06-30 23:45:00     6265.8
    2019-06-30 23:50:00     6282.0
    2019-06-30 23:55:00     6217.7
```

It gives this error :

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Answer (score 1):

check that `df[df.index.duplicated()]` return the duplicate value?
if yes,

use `df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]` to remove duplicates

this might be one such reason. share your `df.sample(5)` to get a better idea

Edit:
Based on your head & tail data, first suggestion is to use

`df = pd.read_excel('practice.xlsx',index_col=0,parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']])`

this will merge your date and time column.

now  `df = df.asfreq(freq='5T')` will work.

further if you want to resample it in hour frequency use `df.resample('H', how='mean')`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'D' or 'H' as your index and the index has the same value which is not allowed. You try to assign to a column when the index has duplicates or single value.

It is advisable to share a sample data that your error is replicated.

Comment: My data is not hourly nor in minutes. My data-set is in step of five minutes so, could you help how to set frequency on data which having five minutes step data

Comment: @Rikin can you edit your question and share a sample data?

Comment: I have edited my question and added my data-set. Please help me.